# Cannot bind mesh to armature?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting, 2d

So I was going to create an MWE for [my other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118960/weights-not-showing-in-weight-paint-mode), only to find that I can't seem to get what worked in the larger example to work here. :P

So I set up the bendy bones

[image]

Now to bind the girl to the armature like I did before ...

[image]

Nope, doesn't work.

And if I go into weight paint mode and set it to solid, it's all grey.

[image]

How do I bind this properly?

[image]

Comment: You have hidden geometry in your mesh (turn off Mask modifier and press ALT-H in edit mode to see it), which is a big plane. It messes up all v-group calculations during binding. Once you delete it or apply Mask modifier, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @SergeL Yup, looks like I messed up when I created the mesh. Thanks a lot. Want to make an answer out of it?

Comment: I am a bit lazy. Answer yourself, please